# Canvas Resize Browser - addEventListener 'resize'

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, html5-canvas, fabricjs

For some time I am trying to deploy responsive canvas.
I managed to get to load the canvas, the size suit according to the screen. But the problem is that if you resize the screen the canvas is always the size that was uploaded.

https://jsfiddle.net/gislef/fvzj7z1d/

Now I'm trying trying to implement the resize, but there is some error in it if all functions carry then canvas is resized often.

https://jsfiddle.net/gislef/ua9a20aL/2/

```
 window.addEventListener('resize', function(){

      if ((widthscrencan >=361) || (widthscrencan ==768)){ 

          zoomIn768()
      } 
    }, false);


    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){   
      if ((widthscrencan >=769) || (widthscrencan ==992)){ 

          zoomIn992()
      }
    }, false);  


    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){   
      if ((widthscrencan >=993) || (widthscrencan ==1200)){ 

          zoomIn1200() 
      }

    }, false);

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){   
      if (widthscrencan >=1300){ 

          zoomIn1300()          
      }
     }, false);
```

I am newbie with javascript lately I have endeavored to learn

Thanks for any help

Comment: With this setup, if screen is larger than 1300 you are going for all the possible resizes. because 1300 is >= of 361, 769, 993, 1300.

Comment: Thank you, yes I realize it. I do not know how to solve yet